# Tricky trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I stumbled upon this trigonometric equation:
$$2\cos^2(x)-5x+2=0$$
for $0<x<2\pi$, and I don't know how to solve it analytically (the task explicitly says not to use a calculator).

I know that you can rearrange the question like this:
$$2\cos^2(x)-5x+2=0$$
$$2\cos^2(x)-1=5x-3$$
$$\cos(2x)=5x-3$$

but I don't know how this should be useful.

My textbook says that the solutions are $\frac \pi 3$ and $\frac {5\pi} 3$. However, these are the solutions to the equation:
$$2\cos^2(x)-5\cos(x)+2=0$$
so I'm sure my textbook made a little mistake there (and I know how to solve such an equation).
Nonetheless I'm curious how to solve the "wrong" equation. Is there even a way to solve it without graphs?

Comment: one could find the number of solutiosn and possibly an approximate interval in which a root lies ,else   I dont see any general way to solve such equations

Comment: Meant to add:  I think the original is a typo.

Comment: Agree it is a typo. You cannot solve the original equation analytically.

Comment: There are three numerical methods that spring to mind.  All need a calculator.  (1) If you can use calculus, the [Newton Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) method.  (2) Interval bisection: find two points for which the expression has opposite signs, so a zero must lie in the interval.  Then test the mid point and so iteratively reduce the size of the interval as far as you need.  (3) write it as $x = (\cos(2x)+3)/5$ and iterate.  (1) and (2) can deliver arbitrary levels of accuracy, (1) is generally faster. (3) works only for some problems, but this is one such.

Comment: Okay, I was wondering because the only other ideas I had in mind were approximation methods, too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Even an approximation method will not help much, since the root is $\approx 0.653$ let say we use Bhaskara formula $\cos(x)\approx\frac{\pi^2-4x^2}{\pi^2+x^2}$ which is adapted for this interval, then you get a cubic polynomial to solve and the solution is too ugly for hand calculation anyway.

Comment: agreed, you end up with $20x^3+4x^2+5\pi^2x-4\pi^2=0$ where you don't have any option but use cardano's formula or such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question has been answered, this is simply a comment that I can accept to close this question.